# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on string in

Tags: php, datetime

I have order date time stored in mysql database.
I am getting it. Now I am converting it to users local timezone and then adding 1 day in it.

Now What I am looking to do is getting how many hours and minutes remain in above date time in compare of current localtime of user. My code is like below

```
$timestamp_pending_accept = strtotime($pending_accept_row['order_time']);
$order_expiry_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp_pending_accept));
$local_time = convert_timezone($order_expiry_date,$_SESSION['user_timezone'],SERVER_TIMEZONE);
$datetime = new DateTime();
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($_SESSION['user_timezone']);
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
$now = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$interval = $order_expiry_date->diff($now);
$remaining_time = $interval->format("%h h, %i m");
echo $remaining_time;
```

But its giving me error called

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on string in
```

I am not getting idea how to solve the issue, Let me know if anyone here can help me for do the same.

Thanks!

Comment: The error is obvious because `$order_expiry_date` is a string and not a DateTime object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fatal error raises in this line:

```
<?php
$interval = $order_expiry_date->diff($now);
```

It means that you try to call `diff` method of `object`, but `$order_expiry_date` has type of `string`.

Add debug statement before the line to ensure:

```
<?php 
var_dump($order_expiry_date);exit;
$interval = $order_expiry_date->diff($now);
```

It should output something like `string(19) "2021-06-26 15:55:32"`.

To fix the error, you should do some steps:

1. Convert `$order_expiry_date` from string to [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/class.datetime.php) object.
2. Replace `$now` argument (its type is also string) with Datetime object

Result is below:

```
<?php
/* region for demonstration */
$pending_accept_row['order_time'] = '2021-06-25 15:55:32';

$_SESSION['user_timezone'] = 'UTC';
define('SERVER_TIMEZONE', 'UTC');

function convert_timezone($date, $user_timezone, $server_timezone) {
  return $date;
}
/* endregion */

$timestamp_pending_accept = strtotime($pending_accept_row['order_time']);
$order_expiry_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp_pending_accept));
$local_time = convert_timezone($order_expiry_date,$_SESSION['user_timezone'],SERVER_TIMEZONE);
$datetime = new DateTime();
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($_SESSION['user_timezone']);
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
// no need to convert DateTime to string
// $now = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$order_expiry_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $order_expiry_date);
// $interval = $order_expiry_date->diff($now);
$interval = $order_expiry_date->diff($datetime);
$remaining_time = $interval->format("%h h, %i m");
echo $remaining_time;
```

[Live demo on PHP sandbox.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c19bf5b0a155b20d65bade3e505d356055d2378)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! It have solved my issue!